# wso2esb4.6.0 giving errors in particular local machine

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

i am using wso2esb 4.6.0 and wso2dss3.0.1 both r giving errors like 
Port already in use I fix this using kill commend .Now its giving database errors like
 INFO - AgentDS Successfully deployed Agent Client

```
[2013-10-28 10:43:30,001] ERROR - DatabaseUtil Database Error - General error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: page[325] data leaf table:0 entries:16 parent:144 keys:[506, 508, 510, 512, 514, 516, 522, 528, 530, 532, 534, 545, 547, 549, 551, 553] offsets:[1936, 1825, 1713, 1601, 1488, 1374, 1262, 1150, 1038, 926, 815, 702, 589, 478, 366, 253] parent 144 expected 28" [50000-140]
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: page[325] data leaf table:0 entries:16 parent:144 keys:[506, 508, 510, 512, 514, 516, 522, 528, 530, 532, 534, 545, 547, 549, 551, 553] offsets:[1936, 1825, 1713, 1601, 1488, 1374, 1262, 1150, 1038, 926, 815, 702, 589, 478, 366, 253] parent 144 expected 28" [50000-140]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:327)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:156)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:279)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:237)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:202)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:56)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:146)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.getSession(Engine.java:125)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.createSession(Session.java:122)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:241)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.createSession(SessionRemote.java:219)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:111)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:95)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:73)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:277)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:694)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:626)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:127)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.claim.dao.ClaimDAO.getDialectCount(ClaimDAO.java:159)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.populateProfileAndClaimMaps(DefaultRealm.java:309)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:109)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:218)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:116)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:67)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: page[325] data leaf table:0 entries:16 parent:144 keys:[506, 508, 510, 512, 514, 516, 522, 528, 530, 532, 534, 545, 547, 549, 551, 553] offsets:[1936, 1825, 1713, 1601, 1488, 1374, 1262, 1150, 1038, 926, 815, 702, 589, 478, 366, 253] parent 144 expected 28
    at org.h2.message.DbException.throwInternalError(DbException.java:226)
    at org.h2.index.PageDataIndex.getPage(PageDataIndex.java:231)
    at org.h2.index.PageDataNode.getLastKey(PageDataNode.java:221)
    at org.h2.index.PageDataIndex.<init>(PageDataIndex.java:74)
    at org.h2.table.RegularTable.<init>(RegularTable.java:75)
    at org.h2.store.PageStore.addMeta(PageStore.java:1443)
    at org.h2.store.PageStore.readMetaData(PageStore.java:1380)
    at org.h2.store.PageStore.recover(PageStore.java:1178)
    at org.h2.store.PageStore.openExisting(PageStore.java:317)
    at org.h2.store.PageStore.open(PageStore.java:271)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.getPageStore(Database.java:2059)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:534)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:207)
    ... 39 more
[2013-10-28 10:43:30,012] ERROR - DefaultRealmService Cannot initialize the realm.
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Database Error - General error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: page[325] data leaf table:0 entries:16 parent:144 keys:[506, 508, 510, 512, 514, 516, 522, 528, 530, 532, 534, 545, 547, 549, 551, 553] offsets:[1936, 1825, 1713, 1601, 1488, 1374, 1262, 1150, 1038, 926, 815, 702, 589, 478, 366, 253] parent 144 expected 28" [50000-140]
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.claim.dao.ClaimDAO.getDialectCount(ClaimDAO.java:169)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.populateProfileAndClaimMaps(DefaultRealm.java:309)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:109)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:218)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:116)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:67)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: page[325] data leaf table:0 entries:16 parent:144 keys:[506, 508, 510, 512, 514, 516, 522, 528, 530, 532, 534, 545, 547, 549, 551, 553] offsets:[1936, 1825, 1713, 1601, 1488, 1374, 1262, 1150, 1038, 926, 815, 702, 589, 478, 366, 253] parent 144 expected 28" [50000-140]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:327)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:156)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:279)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:237)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:202)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:56)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:146)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.getSession(Engine.java:125)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.createSession(Session.java:122)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:241)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.createSession(SessionRemote.java:219)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:111)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:95)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:73)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:277)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:694)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:626)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:127)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.claim.dao.ClaimDAO.getDialectCount(ClaimDAO.java:159)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: page[325] data leaf table:0 entries:16 parent:144 keys:[506, 508, 510, 512, 514, 516, 522, 528, 530, 532, 534, 545, 547, 549, 551, 553] offsets:[1936, 1825, 1713, 1601, 1488, 1374, 1262, 1150, 1038, 926, 815, 702, 589, 478, 366, 253] parent 144 expected 28
    at org.h2.message.DbException.throwInternalError(DbException.java:226)
    at org.h2.index.PageDataIndex.getPage(PageDataIndex.java:231)
    at org.h2.index.PageDataNode.getLastKey(PageDataNode.java:221)
    at org.h2.index.PageDataIndex.<init>(PageDataIndex.java:74)
    at org.h2.table.RegularTable.<init>(RegularTable.java:75)
    at org.h2.store.PageStore.addMeta(PageStore.java:1443)
    at org.h2.store.PageStore.readMetaData(PageStore.java:1380)
    at org.h2.store.PageStore.recover(PageStore.java:1178)
    at org.h2.store.PageStore.openExisting(PageStore.java:317)
    at org.h2.store.PageStore.open(PageStore.java:271)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.getPageStore(Database.java:2059)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:534)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:207)
    ... 39 more
[2013-10-28 10:43:30,021] ERROR - Activator Cannot start User Manager Core bundle
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Cannot initialize the realm.
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:222)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:116)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:67)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Database Error - General error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: page[325] data leaf table:0 entries:16 parent:144 keys:[506, 508, 510, 512, 514, 516, 522, 528, 530, 532, 534, 545, 547, 549, 551, 553] offsets:[1936, 1825, 1713, 1601, 1488, 1374, 1262, 1150, 1038, 926, 815, 702, 589, 478, 366, 253] parent 144 expected 28" [50000-140]
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.claim.dao.ClaimDAO.getDialectCount(ClaimDAO.java:169)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.populateProfileAndClaimMaps(DefaultRealm.java:309)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:109)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:218)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: page[325] data leaf table:0 entries:16 parent:144 keys:[506, 508, 510, 512, 514, 516, 522, 528, 530, 532, 534, 545, 547, 549, 551, 553] offsets:[1936, 1825, 1713, 1601, 1488, 1374, 1262, 1150, 1038, 926, 815, 702, 589, 478, 366, 253] parent 144 expected 28" [50000-140]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:327)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:156)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:279)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:237)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:202)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:56)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:146)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.getSession(Engine.java:125)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.createSession(Session.java:122)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:241)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.createSession(SessionRemote.java:219)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:111)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:95)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:73)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:277)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:694)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:626)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:127)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.claim.dao.ClaimDAO.getDialectCount(ClaimDAO.java:159)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: page[325] data leaf table:0 entries:16 parent:144 keys:[506, 508, 510, 512, 514, 516, 522, 528, 530, 532, 534, 545, 547, 549, 551, 553] offsets:[1936, 1825, 1713, 1601, 1488, 1374, 1262, 1150, 1038, 926, 815, 702, 589, 478, 366, 253] parent 144 expected 28
    at org.h2.message.DbException.throwInternalError(DbException.java:226)
    at org.h2.index.PageDataIndex.getPage(PageDataIndex.java:231)
    at org.h2.index.PageDataNode.getLastKey(PageDataNode.java:221)
    at org.h2.index.PageDataIndex.<init>(PageDataIndex.java:74)
    at org.h2.table.RegularTable.<init>(RegularTable.java:75)
    at org.h2.store.PageStore.addMeta(PageStore.java:1443)
    at org.h2.store.PageStore.readMetaData(PageStore.java:1380)
    at org.h2.store.PageStore.recover(PageStore.java:1178)
    at org.h2.store.PageStore.openExisting(PageStore.java:317)
    at org.h2.store.PageStore.open(PageStore.java:271)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.getPageStore(Database.java:2059)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:534)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:207)
    ... 39 more
```

how can i avoid this is this my machine issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting errors like Port already in use, when using more than one WSO2 product, that means you are trying to start both products in the same port. Please make sure you have set the port off set(change) value uniquely, in Carbon.xml (CARBON_HOME/repository/conf/carbon.xml) and then start the servers again.

IE

```
  <Offset>0</Offset>
```

Comment: thanx have you go through my question i pasted my error my current error

Comment: Looks like your H2 database is corrupted .. The recommended approach is to mount your registry database on an enterprise ready database (such as mysql) for the moment you can replace your H2 database folder with a fresh pack (folder location CARBON_HOME/repository/database)